# Bot Composer UTC time recognition

Tags: botframework

[image: Input and output]

Can someone explain why this IF statement is returning false if the current UTC time is 16:21 and the function is to return true if the current UTC time is >=09:00:00 && <=17:00:00

Have tried separate IF statements and extending the time bracket beyond reasonable doubt

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you're comparing a UTC time object to a string representation of the time. `utcTime == string` will not evaluate to true since a UTC time object and a string cannot be the same, and the UTC time converted to a string would not take the same format (as you can see when you printed the time.

The solution would be to instead create two UTC time objects with their values set to 09:00:00 and 17:00:00 respectively and comparing the current time to those instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
= utcNow('HH:mm:ss') >= `09:00:00` && utcNow('HH:mm:ss') < `17:00:00`
```

Solution to question. Needed to enter time format similar to that of UTC format.